# In RoR how do I dynamically show and limit the number of characters allowable?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

For example, the comments in SO shows the number of allowable characters remaining.  Basically, how do I do that in ruby on rails?

Comment: This shows that I only have 600 characters left and what does it do when I get to the last set of available characters?  Will it give me a warning, boy 600 characters is a heck of alot to be typing I thought it was alot shorter than that.

Comment: This is a javascript question. It happens client side so Rails isn't that helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done on JavaScript side, as mentioned in comment.

This page provides nicely explained example: [Interactive character limit for textarea using jQuery](http://www.ajaxray.com/blog/2007/11/09/interactive-character-limit-for-textarea-using-jquery/) (it also contains an example of doing it without jQuery).

Comment: HOw do I install the jQuery library?  I think rails only comes with prototype?

Comment: I guess you are better off implementing it with Prototype if you are already using it.

Comment: um, how do I add the onkey when using ruby on rails textarea?

Comment: nevermind....I implemented it and it's not showing up.  I put the javascript code into the actual application.js file which is called and I checked the source code.

Comment: Hi, I am using the non-jQuery method and it doesn't appear to be working.  Any experience on this?

Comment: Well it's kind of hard to guess what could be wrong. It would be best if you provided a link to your site.